# Cortana ran into an issue

Tags: cortana

I have created a javascript application (aka UWA) in order to play with my Belkin wemo and then turn on or turn off the ligth with Cortana. The following function is well called but Cortana ends up with an issue. If I remove the call to the HTTP call, the program works fine. Who can tell me what's wrong with the following function because no more details are exposed unfortunately (of course in the real program  is replaced with the right URL):

```
    function setWemo(status) {

    WinJS.xhr({ url: "<url>" }).then(function () {
        var userMessage = new voiceCommands.VoiceCommandUserMessage();

        userMessage.spokenMessage = "Light is now turned " + status;

        var statusContentTiles = [];

        var statusTile = new voiceCommands.VoiceCommandContentTile();
        statusTile.contentTileType = voiceCommands.VoiceCommandContentTileType.titleOnly;
        statusTile.title = "Light is set to: " + status;

        statusContentTiles.push(statusTile);

        var response = voiceCommands.VoiceCommandResponse.createResponse(userMessage, statusContentTiles);

        return voiceServiceConnection.reportSuccessAsync(response);

    }).done();

}
```

Comment: My first question would be, are you issuing any kind of call to [ReportProgressAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.voicecommands.voicecommandserviceconnection.reportprogressasync.aspx)? Cortana won't let the background task hang indefinitely, you have to send *something* to show the user at least once every 5 seconds, and getting a progress message up should be the first thing you do. If that xhr call is taking a while, I'd look into running something that periodically sends progress messages in parallel while it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your background task has access to the WinJS namespace. For background tasks, since there isn't any default.html, base.js won't be getting imported automatically unless you explicitly do it.

I had to update winjs to version 4.2 [from here](http://try.buildwinjs.com/) (or the source repository on git), then add that to my project to update from the released version that comes with VS 2015. WinJS 4.0 has a bug where it complains about gamepad controls if you try to import it this way (see [this MSDN forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/10425325-e52f-4507-8fd0-0bba0bee2f42/uwphtmlbackground-task-javascript-runtime-error-winjs-is-undefined?forum=wpdevelop))

Then I added a line like

```
importScripts("/Microsoft.WinJS.4.0/js/base.js");
```

to the top of your script's starting code to import WinJS. Without this, you're probably getting an error like "WinJS is undefined" popping up in your debug console, but for some reason, whenever I hit that, I wasn't getting a debug break in visual studio. This was causing the Cortana session to just hang doing nothing, never sending a final response.

I'd also add that you should be handling errors and handling progress, so that you can periodically send progress reports to Cortana to ensure that it does not time you out (which is why it gives you the error, probably after around 5 seconds):

```
WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://urlhere/", responseType: "text" }).done(function completed(webResponse) {
                ... handle response here
   },
   function error(errorResponse) {
        ... error handling
   },
   function progress(requestProgress) {
      ... <some kind of check to see if it's been longer than a second or two here since the last progress report>
       var userProgressMessage = new voiceCommands.VoiceCommandUserMessage();

       userProgressMessage.DisplayMessage = "Still working on it!";
       userProgressMessage.SpokenMessage = "Still working on it";

       var response = voiceCommands.VoiceCommandResponse.createResponse(userProgressMessage);
       return voiceServiceConnection.reportProgressAsync(response);
  });
```

Comment: I have downloaded the new version as well as imported base.js at the top and now the url is called ! Thanks a lot.